# Load an image outside viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

It's possible to load an image outside viewport using javascript?

I've been researching about this, but with no lucky.

For example load an image outside the viewport so then i can apply lateral transition to make appear the image already loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Image` object, load it, but not append to your DOM:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    // When called, image is loaded, but it is not added to DOM
    // You can do whatever you want with it
};

img.src = "http://example.com/image.png";
```

Comment: You need to set `img.onload` *before* `img.src` or the callback won't get called.

Comment: I should do with many pictures and I do not want to overload the initial charge.

Comment: @PabloLevin Honestly said, I do not understand you. What do you mean by "overload the initial charge"?

Comment: Why would it matter when you set the `onload` Event? Why can't you set the `src` first? It shouldn't matter, since that is an Event that fires once the Image is loaded.

Comment: Great and if I'm carrying is all wordpress post with images and text using ajax. with overload I meant to not load all images at the boot of the page.

Comment: I want to create this effect using ajax in wordpress, http://oneup.themes.tf/new-modules-in-v1-5/#portfolio       but I have problem to calc height of ajax div because of images

Comment: @PHPglue I agree it's a little weird. Setting `src` is what actually starts the request. If `onload` is not set before `src` when the request is sent there's no callback to call.

Comment: @PabloLevin This happens asynchronously. It does not 'overload' anything, the browser won't stop and wait. The page will still function, the images just won't have loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

The foolproof way:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'pathToImage.png';
img.onload = function(){
  // fires when image found at `pathToImage.png` is loaded
}
```

Note that you don't have to append any Element to the DOM, if you don't want to. `var img = new  Image();` does the same thing, but I believe it only became a W3C Recommendation (REC) as of HTML5, so, although it's always worked for me, it may not work in some older Browsers.

If you want to load a bunch of Images, not Asynchronously:

```
var imgs = ['img0.png', 'img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'];
for(var i=0,l=imgs.length; i<l; i++){
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = imgs[i];
  // if you're not doing anything Asynchronously, no need for img.onload
  img.onload = function(){
    console.log('Image at increment `'+i+'` has loaded.');
  }
}
```

Comment: And if I have to load more than 1 image?

Comment: @PabloLevin Then you would do this multiple times (potentially in a loop or something if there were lots)

Comment: If you are doing it Asynchronously, you would have to put all of the next Image code inside the `img.onload = function(){/* in here */}`, otherwise you can use a loop, or recursive function.